Can i run cloud run jobs locally
Can i run cloud run jobs locally in an emulator and how.
I have been researching google cloud technologies and i can not find a suitable technology that enables me to create simple background jobs that have long running times while being scalable and relatively easy to implement.
I have resource intensive task that has to be scalable for each user and each integration cost is not an issue.
Best Regards

Seems there is no  direct emulator or local development environment for Cloud Run Jobs, see this workaround in github, check if this is helpful?

A with all other google cloud tech i dont know what they are thinking but azure and aws are killing them. Thanks for the info

This github repo sounds interesting! However, what do you want to test locally? The task parallelization, task replaying and stuff related to the task? Not a single instance run I guess.

@guillaumeblaquiere even single instance run would be ok. I would also like to debug as well

In that case, it's simply running a container! Build and run your container. If you want to inject your credential in the container, you can use my articles. https://medium.com/google-cloud/run-your-app-locally-as-if-you-were-on-google-cloud-2722e33e5656 Without task management, Cloud Run Job stay a basic and simple service.

@guillaumeblaquiere is there a way to debug a cloud run job what would be steps to setup that in a container

No, only log trace can help you to understand the behavior

@guillaumeblaquiere now you see the shortcomings of the whole gcp platform

Not really, it's only a different mindset, another way to see computing, cloud computing, serverless and services. Google Cloud is disruptive on many points, and rarely for worse. Many are not yet ready for this new age !

Seems there is no direct emulator or local development environment for Cloud Run Jobs.
Also as mentioned the workaround  with local testing and development workflows using Docker at github

This emulator tries to emulate the behavior of Cloud Run Jobs. As of this writing, Google does not provide a Cloud Run Jobs emulator, which makes local development a huge pain. This project aims to help you out until they do release an official emulator.

Please note that the above project is not associated with Google and not an official one.
To bring it to Google notice  I would recommend you to raise a new public issue tracker with your use case details and you may track the progress over there..
